# Can I use verb as noun in a informal way? Informal Japanese

Tags: english-to-japanese, nouns, pronouns, informal

I've tried searching for the answer in a lot of place. But all I get is formal answers (like **彼女はいつ来ますか**). I'm assuming that the informal style will be **彼女はいつ来てるのか。** because the verb **come** turned into **coming** and is acting like a noun so, I added a **の**　at the end of it. Is it correct? Google translate doesn't do a good job with informal styles. So can anybody say how a native Japanese a boy would say this to his high school friend? This will give me ideas to apply this to a lot of other places. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you explain more what your reason for making it 来てる and adding の was? If you just want to change the register, why did you also change the grammar?

Comment: I can't explain to you any better. Sorry! I'm a begginer. I don't understand the grammar stuff very well. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Related:  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34350/is-nominalization-necessary-in-%e5%bd%bc%e3%81%8c%e6%88%bb%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8b%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99

Answer (score 2):

The informal version of "彼女はいつ来ますか？" is "彼女はいつ来るの？"

- "のか？" is a literary style, and it almost never happens in ordinary conversations in the real world.
- `BE + -ING` (eg "She is coming tomorrow") is an **English** way of expressing future tense. Japanese ている doesn't have such a function.

See: https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/question-markers/

(By the way, if you want to make it really natural, don't use 彼女. An average Japanese boy doesn't use it more than once a month.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say 彼女はいつ来るの? Just adding の right after the base form of verb works. This rule can be applied to other verbs like 戻る, 帰る, and so on.

However, Japanese don't use 彼女, 彼 or 私たち so often. I actually pictured myself speaking and figured out that it would be more natural if we omit subjectives or specify persons' names. e.g. いつ来るの?, Mary はいつ来るの?